# Elasticsearch conditionally collapse results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following products indexed:

```
[
    {
        "title": "ProductA",
        "group": "A",
        "noOfGroupProducts": 3
    },
    {
        "title": "ProductB",
        "group": "A",
        "noOfGroupProducts": 3
    },
    {
        "title": "ProductC",
        "group": "A",
        "noOfGroupProducts": 3
    },
    {
        "title": "ProductD",
        "group": "B",
        "noOfGroupProducts": 2
    },
    {
        "title": "ProductE",
        "group": "B",
        "noOfGroupProducts": 2
    }
]
```

I want to get the following result:

1. If I search for something that matches all products in a group, those are collapsed

   ```
   [
       {
           "group": "A",
           "docs": [
               {
                   "title": "ProductA",
                   "group": "A",
                   "noOfGroupProducts": 3
               },
               {
                   "title": "ProductB",
                   "group": "A",
                   "noOfGroupProducts": 3
               },
               {
                   "title": "ProductC",
                   "group": "A",
                   "noOfGroupProducts": 3
               }
           ]
       },
       {
           "title": "ProductD",
           "group": "B",
           "noOfGroupProducts": 2
       }
   ]
   ```
2. If search for something that matches only some of the products in a group, they are not collapsed

   ```
   [
       {
           "title": "ProductA",
           "group": "A",
           "noOfGroupProducts": 3
       },
       {
           "title": "ProductC",
           "group": "A",
           "noOfGroupProducts": 3
       }
   ]
   ```

I can change the index structure and I thought about different things like using nested products and exploding them in results (pagination problem).

Is this solvable with basic Elasticsearch features or even scripting or do I need to write a plugin?

Comment: How would ES know what "all products" means?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I guess it's the `noOfGroupProducts` field, but not sure. @HansHöchtl?

Comment: It doesn't look like something ES should do. The collapsing part is with aggregations, but the not-collapsed part is regular search result. So the condition would be: if matched `doc_count` per group == `noOfGroupProducts` then go ahead and perform an aggregation, if not then just give me the documents. Sounds like something to be done outside ES.

Comment: Agreed, it's something that belongs to the client side in my opinion, too.